# How can I get the date of Wednesdays from now until every week by carbon?

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

For example, today is Tuesday, `22-12-2012`
For entry I have `Wednesday` and the number `three`.
I want these dates...

```
2021-12-23
2021-12-29
2022-01-05
```

echo \Carbon\Carbon::now()->next('Wednesday')->toDateString();

i want replace the Wednesday to the number, Because my input is Persian.

```
$numberWeek = [
    'شنبه' => 0,
    'یکشنبه' => 1,
    'دوشنبه' => 2,
    'سه شنبه' => 3,
    'چهارشنبه' => 4,
    'پنجشنبه' => 5,
    'جمعه' => 6,
];
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple ways.
One of them

```
echo \Carbon\Carbon::now()->next('Wednesday')->toDateString();
echo \Carbon\Carbon::now()->next('Wednesday')->addWeeks(1)->toDateString();
echo \Carbon\Carbon::now()->next('Wednesday')->addWeeks(2)->toDateString();
```

If you want to have it as loop:

```
$date = '2021-12-22';
$number = 3;
$i = 0;

while ($i < $number) {
    echo \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date)->next('Wednesday')->addWeeks($i)->toDateString()."\n";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use numbers instead of Wednesday?
Our calendar is Persian, for example, send the number 4 for the Wednesday.

$numberWeek = [
    'شنبه' => 0,
    'یکشنبه' => 1,
    'دوشنبه' => 2,
    'سه شنبه' => 3,
    'چهارشنبه' => 4,
    'پنجشنبه' => 5,
    'جمعه' => 6,
];

Comment: @MohammadAfshar , that should work as well. I.e: `echo \Carbon\Carbon::now()->next(3)->toDateString();`  Keep in mind that [*Day of week numbers* are **zero-indexed** starting from *Sunday*](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#:~:text=Day%20of%20week%20number%20%28from%200%20%28Sunday%29%20to%206%20%28Saturday%29%29%2C%20similar%20to%20%22d%22%20but%20this%20one%20is%20translatable%20%28takes%20first%20day%20of%20week%20of%20the%20current%20locale%29)

Comment: Another problem with this code ,
if today is Wednesday,
it will not register today

Comment: @MohammadAfshar , In that case, you may want to register the actual *timezone* (`->setTimezone("+3:30")`) in your computation. I.e: `echo \Carbon\Carbon::now()->setTimezone("+03:30")->next(3)->toDateString();`

Answer (score 0):

Another method is mentioned below.

```php
$now = Carbon::now();

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    echo $now->addWeeks($i)->weekdays(3)->format('Y-m-d');
}
```